# Given k convolution filters of size f with an image of size D and stride s, how many features does a 1D convolution generate?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network

I was trying to figure out the number of units/features that one would get after doing a 1D convolution. Assume the condition of the question namely:

1. k convolution filters
2. of size f
3. with an image of size D
4. and stride s

then, how many features does a 1D convolution generate?

To figure this out I drew a couple of examples. First for  simplest $s = 1$. It seems that for this special case its just how many times one can slide the filter until it reaches the end of the vector/signal/image in $R^D$. It seems to be that for 1 filter we have

$$D - f+1$$

features. So in total features x number_if_filters = (D - f + 1)k

However, when the stride is as big as a filter $s = f$, then it seems that the answer is just how many times the filter fits in the input image (not that $s \leq f$ seems really weird so I thought $s = f$ was the largest stride that made sense). In this case we would have for 1 filter:

$$ \left \lfloor {\frac{D}{f}} \right \rfloor  $$

features. So in total features x number_if_filters = \left \lfloor {\frac{D}{f}} \right \rfloork

however, I was having a hard time coming up with a general formula with $s$ as a part of the equation (and obviously some conditions when the formula holds). Can anyone provide some guidance?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the number of outputs of the convolution layer, http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/ gives a good explanation:

> **Spatial arrangement**. We have explained the connectivity of each neuron in the Conv Layer to the input volume, but we haven't yet
> discussed how many neurons there are in the output volume or how they
> are arranged. Three hyperparameters control the size of the output
> volume: the **depth, stride** and **zero-padding**. We discuss these
> next:
>
> 1. First, the **depth** of the output volume is a hyperparameter: it corresponds to the number of filters we would like to use, each
>    learning to look for something different in the input. For example, if
>    the first Convolutional Layer takes as input the raw image, then
>    different neurons along the depth dimension may activate in presence
>    of various oriented edged, or blobs of color. We will refer to a set
>    of neurons that are all looking at the same region of the input as a
>    **depth column** (some people also prefer the term *fibre*).
> 2. Second, we must specify the **stride** with which we slide the filter. When the stride is 1 then we move the filters one pixel at a
>    time. When the stride is 2 (or uncommonly 3 or more, though this is
>    rare in practice) then the filters jump 2 pixels at a time as we slide
>    them around. This will produce smaller output volumes spatially.
> 3. As we will soon see, sometimes it will be convenient to pad the input volume with zeros around the border. The size of this
>    **zero-padding** is a hyperparameter. The nice feature of zero padding is that it will allow us to control the spatial size of the output
>    volumes (most commonly as we'll see soon we will use it to exactly
>    preserve the spatial size of the input volume so the input and output
>    width and height are the same).
>
> We can compute the spatial size of the output volume as a function of
> the input volume size ($W$), the receptive field size of the Conv
> Layer neurons ($F$), the stride with which they are applied ($S$), and
> the amount of zero padding used ($P$) on the border. You can convince
> yourself that the correct formula for calculating how many neurons
> "fit" is given by $(W - F + 2P)/S + 1$. For example for a 7x7 input
> and a 3x3 filter with stride 1 and pad 0 we would get a 5x5 output.
> With stride 2 we would get a 3x3 output. Lets also see one more
> graphical example:
>
> [image]
>
> Illustration of spatial arrangement. In this example there is only one
> spatial dimension (x-axis), one neuron with a receptive field size of
> F = 3, the input size is W = 5, and there is zero padding of P = 1.
> **Left:** The neuron strided across the input in stride of S = 1,
> giving output of size (5 - 3 + 2)/1+1 = 5. **Right:** The neuron
> uses stride of S = 2, giving output of size (5 - 3 + 2)/2+1 = 3.
> Notice that stride S = 3 could not be used since it wouldn't fit
> neatly across the volume. In terms of the equation, this can be
> determined since (5 - 3 + 2) = 4 is not divisible by 3.
>
> The neuron weights are in this example [1,0,-1] (shown on very right),
> and its bias is zero. These weights are shared across all yellow
> neurons (see parameter sharing below).
>
> *Use of zero-padding*. In the example above on left, note that the input dimension was 5 and the output dimension was equal: also 5. This
> worked out so because our receptive fields were 3 and we used zero
> padding of 1. If there was no zero-padding used, then the output
> volume would have had spatial dimension of only 3, because that it is
> how many neurons would have "fit" across the original input. In
> general, setting zero padding to be $P = (F - 1)/2$ when the stride is
> $S = 1$ ensures that the input volume and output volume will have the
> same size spatially. It is very common to use zero-padding in this way
> and we will discuss the full reasons when we talk more about ConvNet
> architectures.
>
> *Constraints on strides*. Note again that the spatial arrangement hyperparameters have mutual constraints. For example, when the input
> has size $W = 10$, no zero-padding is used $P = 0$, and the filter
> size is $F = 3$, then it would be impossible to use stride $S = 2$,
> since $(W - F + 2P)/S + 1 = (10 - 3 + 0) / 2 + 1 = 4.5$, i.e. not an
> integer, indicating that the neurons don't "fit" neatly and
> symmetrically across the input. Therefore, this setting of the
> hyperparameters is considered to be invalid, and a ConvNet library
> could throw an exception or zero pad the rest to make it fit, or crop
> the input to make it fit, or something. As we will see in the ConvNet
> architectures section, sizing the ConvNets appropriately so that all
> the dimensions "work out" can be a real headache, which the use of
> zero-padding and some design guidelines will significantly alleviate.
>
> *Real-world example*. The [Krizhevsky et al.](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/4824-imagenet-classification-with-deep-convolutional-neural-networks)
> architecture that won the ImageNet challenge in 2012 accepted images
> of size [227x227x3]. On the first Convolutional Layer, it used neurons
> with receptive field size $F = 11$, stride $S = 4$ and no zero padding
> $P = 0$. Since (227 - 11)/4 + 1 = 55, and since the Conv layer had a
> depth of $K = 96$, the Conv layer output volume had size [55x55x96].
> Each of the 55*55*96 neurons in this volume was connected to a
> region of size [11x11x3] in the input volume. Moreover, all 96 neurons
> in each depth column are connected to the same [11x11x3] region of the
> input, but of course with different weights. As a fun aside, if you
> read the actual paper it claims that the input images were 224x224,
> which is surely incorrect because (224 - 11)/4 + 1 is quite clearly
> not an integer. This has confused many people in the history of
> ConvNets and little is known about what happened. My own best guess is
> that Alex used zero-padding of 3 extra pixels that he does not mention
> in the paper.
>
> License:
> The MIT License (MIT)
>
> Copyright (c) 2015 Andrej Karpathy
>
> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
> a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
> "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
> without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
> distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
> permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
> the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
> included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
> EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
> MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.
> IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY
> CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT,
> TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE
> SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.*

---

Often, in 1D CNN for natural language processing, the number of features is the number of filters, since a max pooling layer is commonly added after the convolution layer (this way it can easily be applied to input of variable size):

[image]